# No sound after a Software Updater routine update

Tags: 14.04, sound

I have a Dell laptop pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, after a recent auto update from Software Updater I now have no sound.

I did the Audio test on all the devices listed in the Settings-Sound panel and no sound on any.

```
:=> lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
    00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
      Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0704]
      Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

:=>aplay -l
  **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3246 Analog [ALC3246 Analog 
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0] 
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


:=> pactl -list sinks
 pactl list sinks
Sink #8
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 5
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0:  69% 1:  69%
            0: -9.56 dB 1: -9.56 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3246 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3246 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdc328000 irq 131"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d70"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3246"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0256,10280704,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: The driver seems to be fine. Can you please include the output of `aplay -L` and `pactl list sinks` in your question? Did you verify that all the necessary audio channels are unmuted and turned up in `alsamixer`?

Comment: I added teh aplay and pactl outputs... and yes I've checked alsamixer and it all looks ok.